# Recipe fails when building poco with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, makefile, poco

Hi im getting this error when trying to build poco with gcc at cygwin console, it is related with a recipe failed and im not sure how to solved this...

Here is the error code:

```
$ make
make -C /cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/Foundation
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/Foundation'
** Compiling src/ArchiveStrategy.cpp (debug, shared)
g++  -Iinclude -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/CppUnit/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/Foundation/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/XML/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/Util/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/Net/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/Crypto/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/NetSSL_OpenSSL/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/Data/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/Data/SQLite/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/Data/ODBC/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/Data/MySQL/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/Zip/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/PageCompiler/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/PageCompiler/File2Page/include -DPOCO_NO_FPENVIRONMENT -DPOCO_NO_WSTRING -DPOCO_NO_SHAREDMEMORY -DPOCO_BUILD_HOST=PB00YCT7  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500  -g -D_DEBUG  -c src/ArchiveStrategy.cpp -o /cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/Foundation/obj/CYGWIN/x86_64/debug_shared/ArchiveStrategy.o
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create /cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/Foundation/obj/CYGWIN/x86_64/debug_shared/ArchiveStrategy.o: No such file or directory
/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/build/rules/compile:53: recipe for target '/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/Foundation/obj/CYGWIN/x86_64/debug_shared/ArchiveStrategy.o' failed
make[1]: *** [/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/Foundation/obj/CYGWIN/x86_64/debug_shared/ArchiveStrategy.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/Foundation'
Makefile:62: recipe for target 'Foundation-libexec' failed
make: *** [Foundation-libexec] Error 2
```

Here is the bunch of code that is close to the line 53 that is showed as error:

```
$(OBJPATH_DEBUG_SHARED)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(DEPPATH)/%.d
    @echo "** Compiling" $< "(debug, shared)"
    $(CXX) $(INCLUDE) $(CXXFLAGS) $(DEBUGOPT_CXX) $(SHAREDOPT_CXX) -c $< -o $@
```

This may be easy to solve but i haven't figure it out in days because im not an expert on c++ and makefiles.

Update: Im still getting the same error, i will add the complete rule definitions file:

```
# $Id: //poco/1.4/build/rules/compile#1 $
#
# compile
#
# Compile rule definitions for makefiles
#

#
# Targets
#
.PHONY: all all_static all_shared all_debug all_release \
        clean static_debug static_release shared_debug shared_release

all: $(DEFAULT_TARGET)
all_static: static_debug static_release
all_shared: shared_debug shared_release
all_debug: static_debug shared_debug
all_release: static_release shared_release

#
# Create directories if necessary
#
.PHONY: objdirs libdirs bindirs static_bindirs
objdirs: $(OBJPATH_RELEASE_STATIC) $(OBJPATH_DEBUG_STATIC) $(OBJPATH_RELEASE_SHARED) $(OBJPATH_DEBUG_SHARED) 
libdirs: objdirs $(LIBPATH) 
bindirs: objdirs $(BINPATH)
static_bindirs: objdirs $(BINPATH)/static

$(OBJPATH_RELEASE_STATIC) $(OBJPATH_DEBUG_STATIC) $(OBJPATH_RELEASE_SHARED) $(OBJPATH_DEBUG_SHARED) $(LIBPATH) $(BINPATH) $(BINPATH)/static:
    $(MKDIR) $@

#
# Rules for compiling
#   
$(OBJPATH_DEBUG_STATIC)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(DEPPATH)/%.d
    @echo "** Compiling" $< "(debug, static)"
    $(CXX) $(INCLUDE) $(CXXFLAGS) $(DEBUGOPT_CXX) $(STATICOPT_CXX) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJPATH_RELEASE_STATIC)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(DEPPATH)/%.d
    @echo "** Compiling" $< "(release, static)"
    $(CXX) $(INCLUDE) $(CXXFLAGS) $(RELEASEOPT_CXX) $(STATICOPT_CXX) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJPATH_DEBUG_STATIC)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c $(DEPPATH)/%.d
    @echo "** Compiling" $< "(debug, static)"
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUGOPT_CC) $(STATICOPT_CC) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJPATH_RELEASE_STATIC)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c $(DEPPATH)/%.d
    @echo "** Compiling" $< "(release, static)"
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $(RELEASEOPT_CC) $(STATICOPT_CC) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJPATH_DEBUG_SHARED)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(DEPPATH)/%.d
    @echo "** Compiling" $< "(debug, shared)"
    $(CXX) $(INCLUDE) $(CXXFLAGS) $(DEBUGOPT_CXX) $(SHAREDOPT_CXX) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJPATH_RELEASE_SHARED)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(DEPPATH)/%.d
    @echo "** Compiling" $< "(release, shared)"
    $(CXX) $(INCLUDE) $(CXXFLAGS) $(RELEASEOPT_CXX) $(SHAREDOPT_CXX) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJPATH_DEBUG_SHARED)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c $(DEPPATH)/%.d
    @echo "** Compiling" $< "(debug, shared)"
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUGOPT_CC) $(SHAREDOPT_CC) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJPATH_RELEASE_SHARED)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c $(DEPPATH)/%.d
    @echo "** Compiling" $< "(release, shared)"
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $(RELEASEOPT_CC) $(SHAREDOPT_CC) -c $< -o $@

#
# Rules for creating dependency information
#
$(DEPPATH)/%.d: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    @echo "** Creating dependency info for" $^
    $(MKDIR) $(DEPPATH)
    $(DEP) $(SRCDIR)/$(patsubst %.d,%.cpp,$(notdir $@)) $@ $(OBJPATH_DEBUG_STATIC) $(OBJPATH_RELEASE_STATIC) $(OBJPATH_DEBUG_SHARED) $(OBJPATH_RELEASE_SHARED) $(INCLUDE) $(CXXFLAGS) 

$(DEPPATH)/%.d: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    @echo "** Creating dependency info for" $^
    $(MKDIR) $(DEPPATH)
    $(DEP) $(SRCDIR)/$(patsubst %.d,%.c,$(notdir $@)) $@ $(OBJPATH_DEBUG_STATIC) $(OBJPATH_RELEASE_STATIC) $(OBJPATH_DEBUG_SHARED) $(OBJPATH_RELEASE_SHARED) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS)

depend: $(addprefix $(DEPPATH)/,$(addsuffix .d,$(objects)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the problem is that the directory doesn't exist.  The compiler won't create a directory that doesn't exist.  Try modifying your rule to create the directory before invoking the compiler:

```
$(OBJPATH_DEBUG_SHARED)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(DEPPATH)/%.d
        @echo "** Compiling" $< "(debug, shared)"
        mkdir -p $(dir $@)
        $(CXX) $(INCLUDE) $(CXXFLAGS) $(DEBUGOPT_CXX) $(SHAREDOPT_CXX) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: It did not work, i believe the makefile is already making the mkdir, please see the the post i will update it with the entire Compile rule definitions for the makefile.

Comment: I see some targets that have rules which will create directories, but nothing in your makefile depends on those targets, that I can see, so they won't ever be run (unless you run them directly via `make objdirs` or something).  Are you saying that `/cygdrive/c/poco-1.4.6p4-all/Foundation/obj/CYGWIN/x86_64/debug_shared` does exist?  I'm assuming you have permissions to write to that directory and that you have plenty of disk space.  I can't see any reason why the compiler would not be able to create the object file, if all those things are true.